# dplyr mutate in place

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my example

```
library('dplyr')
a <- c(0.2,1.3)
df_test <- data.frame(a)
df_test %>% mutate(a =round(a,0))
```

it produces:

```
  a
1 0
2 1
```

, but does not change original dataframe `df_test`. How do I assign results of mutate to the same dataframe?

Comment: `df_test <- df_test %>% mutate(a =round(a,0))`?

Comment: @Axeman, Thank you!!!

Comment: You should start by reading some R tutorials. There is nothing related to dplyr here really.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I read 2 R tutorials, it is just very difficult for me to wrap my head around R.

Comment: So when you are working with Python or any other language, does any object is being updated by itself without you are using the `=` operator? I know that in pandas you could explicitly specify `inplace=True`, but I don't see why would you assume such thing to be the default behavior of dplyr and even so, why wouldn't you at-least try using the `=` or `<-` operators

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I agree, but for some reason, I thought that `dplyr` would change assignment operator to `%>%` or `%<%`, which I tried. Lack of understanding of unifying philosophy of R, makes me do weird thinks, I agree, that my questions is stupid, but R is wild to me.

Comment: The `%>%` is just equivalent to `.` in most functional languages such as Python or Scala. Though maybe the difference is that unlike in those languages, anything that comes after it doesn't have to be a method of the previous object- hence it's behavior could be sometimes unpredictable. And it's not R. This is just some relatively new operator that was introduced in some package and went viral for some reason. You could very well survive without using it even once. I for instance, have not a single pipe in any code I ever wrote except in my useless SO answers.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Oh I love pipes they make so much sense, I used pipes in MongoDB and pipes are conceptually beautiful.

Comment: Well, apparently you are not the only one

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We can use the `%<>%` compound assignment operator from `magrittr` to change in place

```
library(magrittr)
df_test %<>% 
        mutate(a = round(a,0))
```

---

If we are using `data.table`, the assignment (`:=`) operator does this in place too without copying

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_test)[, a := round(a,0)]
```